# GWT StackLayoutPanel with dynamically sized children

Tags: java, css, gwt

I'm using GWT StackLayoutPanel to present summarized data of reports. For every report, I write it's data to a panel and use it as the child widget of the report name label and add this pair to a StackLayoutPanel.

But the size of the opened stacks seems to be fixed to the overall size of the stackPanel minus the size of the stack headers, and I can't seem to find a way to force the size of the opened panel of the stack, and since the summarized data vary in length, i'm left with blank space for the opened stack that has less Text in them.

[image]

Is there any good way to dynamically force different sizes for each opened stack?

Thanks.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714544/gwt-stacklayoutpanel-dynamic-and-automatic-height) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334216/stacklayoutpanel-has-no-more-place-to-show-the-children-when-there-are-too-many). I guess you'd better write your own widget...

Comment: Yeah, I should have implemented my own widget or use a verticalPanel   filled with DisclosurePanels :(